# How to set up dual-boot Windows with Archlinux?

Tags: windows, boot, grub, arch-linux

I have a fairly recent laptop with ArchLinux (64 bits) as the only OS installed. My motherboard is UEFI and I have a 512 GB SSD. I specify that secure boot is disabled, that I use GRUB as bootloader and that my Archlinux system is encrypted and runs in BTRFS.

How can I install Windows 11 while keeping my current Archlinux system so that I have 2 entries on GRUB?

If possible, I'd like Windows to be encrypted too (via veracrypt for example), and I'd like to have a buffer partition (encrypted too) to store data usable by my two OSes (accessible by both).

Here's my current partition scheme:

```bash
❯ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0           7:0    0  73,9M  1 loop  /var/lib/snapd/snap/core22/817
loop1           7:1    0  73,9M  1 loop  /var/lib/snapd/snap/core22/858
loop2           7:2    0  73,7M  1 loop  /var/lib/snapd/snap/searchsploit/334
loop3           7:3    0  73,8M  1 loop  /var/lib/snapd/snap/searchsploit/352
loop4           7:4    0  53,3M  1 loop  /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/19457
nvme0n1       259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0 475,9G  0 part  
  └─cryptroot 254:0    0 475,9G  0 crypt /var/log
                                         /home
                                         /swap
                                         /.snapshots
                                         /
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The question seems kind of broad. The first steps obviously is to shrink the filesystem, shrink the crypt, and shrink the partition. You may use the exisiting ESP for Windows as well, or you may just let the installer create another one. (If you don't know dism and bcdboot, just change the partition type GUID of the ESP away from `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`, so that Windows wouldn't recognize it; it shouldn't break booting as I have yet to see a UEFI firmware that actually cares about partition type GUID / code.)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why don't you install Windows is a virtual machine running on top of Linux? If you have samba installed, Windows running in the VM will be able to access  files in the Linux file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install windows by keeping my Linux and adding it to GRUB via this tutorial: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Windows_10_with_GRUB

1. I have reduced my main linux partition
2. Then I partitioned like this via `gdisk`

   - 16 MB - 0C01 // Microsoft Reserved Partition
   - 65 GB - 0700 // Microsoft Basic Data
   - 300 MB - 2700 // Windows RE
3. Install windows on the 65 GB partition via a USB key
4. Boot to BIOS, put `GRUB` first in boot order
5. Add Windows to `GRUB` via `osprober`

In the end, I didn't want to create an "exchange" partition. For Windows encryption, the question remains, but this tutorial is a hint: https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/8e010ef0/